# Ruby remove triple quotes

Tags: ruby, csv, set, quotes

I want to put a quoted string into a csv like this:

```
csv << ["\"marks\"", marks]
```

where marks is an integer variable.
The problem is that when I open the CSV, I get this:

```
"""marks""",9
```

Same thing happens with single quotes.
Is there a way to write it in with a single set of quotes? I don't want to have to open the file again and erase them, i just want to print in a quoted string with a single set of quotes. All i want in the CSV is:

```
"marks",9
```

Comment: I've tried adding them in as separate character variables, but that didn't work as well

Comment: Have you tried `"'marks'"`  or `'"marks"'`?

Comment: Same result, also it has to be double quotes, otherwise the output won't pass the check

Comment: You escape a double quote in CSV by doubling it, e.g. if you write `foo"bar` to your CSV it will write out as `foo""bar`. What CSV gem are you using?

Comment: well it's just require 'csv'

Comment: Ahh, CSV is in stdlib. Did not know that. It looks like you have to pass in the `:force_quotes` option to `::new` or `::generate`, then you can just pass in strings and it will quote them. Can you show us more of your code as a starting point for a solution?

Comment: @mwp `:force_quote` will quote every value including the integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one may help:

```
marks = 5
csv=CSV.open("temp.csv", "w", {quote_char: " "})
csv << ["\"marks\"", marks]
csv.close
```

[image: csv in editor]

Comment: You don't need `col_sep:";"`

Comment: Manually quoting things is asking for trouble, so be careful when doing this. The way Ruby quotes and CSV quotes things are completely different. Strings like `test "string"` will likely blow up your CSV file.

Comment: It won't be written correctly, it comes out as invalid CSV data. Also this should be `csv.close` not `cv`. I think @mwp has the correct answer here.

Comment: @tadman I guess you are using single quotes not the escaping. At this case, yeah, it's incorrect.

Comment: If you do `csv << [ 'test "string"', 5 ]` and then try `CSV.parse` on the result you get "Illegal quoting in line 1. (CSV::MalformedCSVError)". Simply slapping quotes on the front and end of that string doesn't fix it either. You need to let the CSV module do its thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
marks = 5
csv = CSV.open('temp.csv', 'w', :force_quotes => true)
csv << ['marks', marks]
csv.close
```

This will have the unfortunate side effect of quoting the numeric values as well, but it might get you where you need to be.

```
$ cat temp.csv 
"marks","5"
```

Comment: Also "5" should be without quotes.

Comment: @tadman: The original had a string with quotes in it because he's trying to force a quoted value to appear in the CSV. This achieves that result, albeit with the numeric value(s) quoted as well.

Comment: @MaximPontyushenko: Yes, as I noted very clearly in my answer. It is not explicit given as a hard requirement in the question and may not be a deal-breaker for the OP if it solves the primary problem. It's merely another option.

Comment: The original question does seem hazy in why that was done, but I agree with your interpretation.

Comment: @mwp I am based on OP's quote: ' All i want in the CSV is: "marks",9 '

Comment: What goes on inside a CSV file is largely irrelevant so long as it can be imported correctly. If you want quotes, this is the way to get them.

Comment: @MaximPontyushenko: A looser interpretation of that statement, in the context of the rest of the question, tells us that he or she is focused on achieving a correctly-quoted string value, and may not care whether or not the numeric value is quoted. Again, this is merely another option.